# Exception during StringFormat: Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I am using log4net to log the information in my .net application, it works as expected, but it is not logging the below string

```
{"SuccessfulMessage":null,"FailedMessage":null,"InvalidMessage":"ID 1234 are invalid","PendingMessage":null,"AlreadyProcessedMessage":null,"InvalidIDMessage":null,"InvalidOperatorMessage":null}
```

It logs the below content when I try to log the above string.

```
<log4net.Error>Exception during StringFormat: Input string was not in a correct format. <format>{"SuccessfulMessage":null,"FailedMessage":null,"InvalidMessage":"ID 1234 are invalid","PendingMessage":null,"AlreadyProcessedMessage":null,"InvalidIDMessage":null,"InvalidOperatorMessage":null}</format><args>{}</args></log4net.Error>
```

I am using the below code to write logs.

```
private ILog AppLogger { get; set; }
AppLogger.InfoFormat(message, args)
```

**Log4net version:** 2.0.8.0

Comment: If your `args` is empty then you should just call `AppLogger.Info(message)`.  If you do have args, then you need to understand that `InfoFormat` takes parameters similar to `String.Format`.  So your `message` would need to be a string like `"{0} for arg[0], {1} etc."` for an `args` with at least 2 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ruzgarustu's answer helped me identify the root cause of the issue.

I solved the issue by the below code. so basically I have removed the enclosing brackets.

```
AppLogger.InfoFormat(message.Trim('{', '}'), args);
```

Answer (score 2):

This exception from String Format seems to arise due to { and } characters, you might need to escape them or replace them with another suitable character.

[image: Below is a screenshot to show how one escape curly braces:]

Comment: Your answer would be much improved if you demonstrated how to escape them.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I updated it with an example screenshot from C# interactive window.

Comment: @ruzgarustu thank you, I have upvoted your answer

Answer (score 0):

You use bad method, use `AppLogger.Info(message)` not `AppLogger.InfoFormat(message, args)`